# Store user credentials in Android keystore/keychain

Tags: android, keystore, keychain, key-storage

I need to store user credentials in `Android keystore`, not in preference. I can store them in it, but it persists till application is on. Once application is killed I am not able to get them as `SecretKey` or `PrivateKey` is lost. Is there any way to get stored values Or keys even after restarting app?.

I have checked multiple samples for this, but none of them helped me to solve my issue. Here are links. https://github.com/afollestad/android-secure-storage
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BasicAndroidKeyStore/
https://github.com/nelenkov/android-keystore

https://codeload.github.com/nelenkov/android-keystore/zip/master

Answer (score 1):

The `AndroidKeyStore` is designed to store and use private key material without revealing it to the app or operating system.
This means you don't store the credentials there, but rather use a key provided by the `AndroidKeyStore` to encrypt your credentials and store the encrypted result.